# getting spreadsheet data to chart data array

Tags: html, google-maps, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-visualization

Although I found similar posts elsewhere, I still cannot solve my issue.
I want to load locations on a html sidebar page on google spreadsheet, but the only example I find are hard-coded locations.

Here is an example, on HTML page (I removed API Key): this one works for me.

```
<body>

    <div class="container">   
        <div id="map_div" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
      </div> <!-- CLOSE CONTAINER -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.charts.load("current", {
          "packages":["map"],
          "mapsApiKey": "xxxx"
      });

      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart(arrayToData) {

        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(

        [["Lat", "Long","Nom"],
           [45.7660889, 4.794056299999999, "Person1"], 
           [45.8167227, 4.8341048, "Person2"], 
           [45.7796433, 4.8037871, "Person3"], 
           [45.7780849, 4.921768399999999, "Person4"]]
           );

        var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

        map.draw(data, {
          showTooltip: true,
          showInfoWindow: true
        });

      }//function drawChart() {

    </script>

  </body>
```

And I would like to have something looking like that, where data locations are not hard-coded but comes from spreadsheet data :

```
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("xxxx");
      var datatable = ss.getRange("listNamesAdresses");

      function drawChart(arrayToData) {

        var dataToArray=document.getElementById("listNamesAdresses");
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
                         dataToArray
                    );

        var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

       map.draw(data, {
          showTooltip: true,
          showInfoWindow: true
        });

      }//function drawChart() {
```

I'm aware this is not correct, but I tried many combinations, still cannot solve it. Your help is welcome !

Here is a sharable example of what I made : 
[Link to a copy of my Map Test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19JUUc-_VquaEjusJc4f5Mm5XubgaPWPi_CahY6O2a3Y/edit?usp=sharing)

I adapted it from my spreadsheet but went out of my quota for my API key, so I could'nt test it yet. I hope this will be fine !
Many thanks in advance

**EDIT 2 :**

I followed ziganotschka's suggestions (thank you very much for your time) : I couldn't apply the HtmlCreateOutputFromFil("index.html") so I stuck to my code for displaying a sidepage Html. For the rest of it : I now have a map (first victory!).
But, it says : "no data points to show".

I checked on values return by getAddresses function, seems OK. For getting easier on it, I changed the function to an easier one : getGeoCodesAndNames. This one returns, as it says, geocode latitude, longitude, and name.

Here are my new code sample and link to the new version of the spreadsheet :
Gs-code :

```
function getGeoCodesAndNames(){
  //get addresses and names list
  var namesAddresses=ss.getRange("ListNamesAddresses");
  var a_values=namesAddresses.getValues();  

  Logger.log(a_values);
  /* returns
  [[Lat, Lon, Name], 
  [45.7660889, 4.79405629999999, person1], 
  [45.8167227, 4.8341048, person2], 
  [45.7796433, 4.8037871, person3], 
  [45.7780849, 4.921768399999999, person4]]  
  */
  return a_values;

}//function getGeoCodesAndNames(){



function testMap2(){   

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("carte2");  
  var html = template.evaluate();
   html.setTitle("Display Map 2").setHeight(550).setWidth(550);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Locations")

}//function testCarte1(){
```

and HTML code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

      window.onload = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getGeoCodesAndNames();

      function onSuccess (arrayToData){

          google.charts.load("current", {
             "packages":["map"],
             "mapsApiKey": "AIzaSyC4WPcWGMZRoqSAfZ0F4RzvWtN6Jy7hmdE"
                           });                  

          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);      

          function drawChart() {      
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayToData);        
            var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));       
            map.draw(data, {
              showTooltip: true,
              showInfoWindow: true
                    });        
          }// function drawChart() {

      }//function onSuccess (arrayToData){


    </script>
```

And here is the link to the new spreadsheet version : 
[TestMap2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r-6NG_vmigYp0HiimZieP4c3SPuEEC1dK7zXjrRcrH4/edit?usp=sharing)

Do I need to publish it as a web app if I just want to have a side page  ? On previous projects I had, I could add datas from a side-page to a spreadsheet without it. In the oppposite ways, can you confirm I need to do it ? I tried, did not change anything on my current result : maybe I made something wrong.

Many thanks again for your help !

**EDIT 3 :** 
I finally got it : My geocode/address function were not returning a proper format for coordinates, because of two things : 
1) I'm using French typing, ie dot are replaced with commas in numbers
2) I had to add one more """ symbol at beginning and ending of each string part in the array.

Here is the correct function (might be improved, but..does the job):

```
function getGeoCodesAndNames(){
  //get addresses and names list
  var namesAddresses=ss.getRange("ListNamesAddresses");
  var a_values=namesAddresses.getValues();  

  for (var i=0;i<a_values.length;i++){   
    for (var j=0;j<a_values[0].length;j++){      
      var value=a_values[i][j];
      if (typeof value == "string"){
        a_values[i][j]="\"" + value + "\"";   
      }
    }    
  }      
  return a_values;      
}//function getGeoCodesAndNames(){
```

Many thanks to the people who helped me !

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We don't know what's in your spreadsheet. You should log what comes out of the spreadsheet and make it the same format than the hardcoded values.

Comment: Thank you for your remark ! Just made it.

Comment: Your hardcoded example contains geographic coordinates while your spreadsheet contains addresses. What about you replace your hardcoded coords by some of the addresses in your spreadsheet? Does it work?

Comment: I saw your comment after the other one. Nonetheless, you saw right, I tried in the opposite way : replace addresses with coordinates in the spreadsheet, for my test's purpose. Do you think that makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

### To combine using the Visualization API in Javascript with retrieving spreadsheet data with Apps Script - you need to use a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Use `google.script.run` to pass data from the serverside to clientside

Sample:

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index.html");
}

function getDatafromSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("xxxx");
  // getNamedRanges()[0] works if you have only one named range
  var datatable = ss.getNamedRanges()[0].getRange().getValues();
  return datatable;  
}
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">   
        <div id="map_div" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
      </div> <!-- CLOSE CONTAINER -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   window.onload = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getDatafromSheet();

   function onSuccess (arrayToData){
      google.charts.load("current", {
          "packages":["map"],
          "mapsApiKey": "AIzaSyDCKzjezYeUDd2ugtFnzokCIpV1YpLmmEc"
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayToData);

      var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

        map.draw(data, {
          showTooltip: true,
          showInfoWindow: true
        });

      }
  }
    </script>
  </body>
```